# Specific variable naming concerns in C

Tags: c, variables, naming-conventions, naming

I am writing a program, and I just have to check: can I name a variable `output` or `input`?
for example:

```
int output;
int input;
```

or is this a pre-assigned name for something else? The modules I'm importing for my program are:

```
#include <pwd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <readline/history.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
```

Comment: Well, can't you just try to run the program? I think (hope) the compiler will inform you of any collision.

Comment: If it were either reserved or already defined, your compiler will produce an error.   Surely just trying it is simpler than asking?  That said if you propose to define these as global symbols, they are particularly poor names, if they are local, then there is not conflict in any case.

Comment: @Clifford okay cool, I just had to check, program's not working, I just wanted to guarantee that wasn't it, and the compiler was missing it for some reason, thanks then!!!

Comment: @prenone okay cool, I just had to check, program's not working, I just wanted to guarantee that wasn't it, and the compiler was missing it for some reason, thanks then!!!

Comment: Then you have asked an [X-Y question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  It will take a long time to fix your real problem if you simply ask whether various hypotheses are plausible.  Ask about your actual problem - but before that use your toolchain's debugger.  For compiled languages, symbol names cannot cause _runtime_ errors - because the symbols do not exist in the compiled code.

Comment: @prenone: The compiler will not inform you if the names are defined inside a block (inside a function) and are the same as external definitions by the included headers because the new definitions hide, rather than conflict, with the prior ones.

Comment: @Clifford: The compiler will not inform you if the names are defined inside a block (inside a function) and are the same as external definitions by the included headers because the new definitions hide, rather than conflict, with the prior ones.

Comment: @EricPostpischil True, but not relevant.  Also I already noted that in my comment - a local symbol 'hiding' one of greater scope is only a problem if it is unintentional, and the higher scope instance were intented.  If that were the case, he would not be asking this specific question, would he?

Comment: @Clifford: An included header may both define an identifier and use it in macros. If the client program defines the identifier at block scope and uses one of those macros, the program will break, but the compiler will not generally produce a warning or diagnostic.

Comment: @EricPostpischil True, but an increasingly narrow target.  As I said, they are poor names for global scope, and you would hope that any library of reasonable quality would avoid them.

Comment: @Clifford: Any library of reasonable quality would avoid using identifiers `input` and `output` in any way exposed to the client. So the question is asking about possibility, not likelhood based on library quality. To answer the question correctly, true possibilities must be stated.

Comment: @Clifford - which compiler has a warning for use of reserved identifiers?  It sounds like a useful check to have.

Comment: @TobySpeight I intended "reserved" in the context of keywords, so in that sense, then of course all compilers.  It was ambiguous and not clear that I was not referring to symbols beginning wit an underscore.

Comment: @Clifford, that's a shame; it would be nice if I could get a warning for naming a function `issue()` after including `<ctype.h>`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are collisions between your variables and any reserved words, the compiler will inform you with a warning or an error in compilation. So if the compilation doesn't produce any error, the names you assign the variables are good.

Comment: If the program defines the symbols inside a block (equivalently, inside a function), the new definitions hide and do not conflict (as far as the compiler is concerned) with external definitions by the libraries. So the compiler would not warn about this.

Comment: @EricPostpischil : Shadowing a symbol you are not using and were not aware existed is neither an error or a problem.  It is rather the purpose and benefit of scope.

Comment: @Clifford: An included header may both define an identifier and use it in macros. If the client program defines the identifier at block scope and uses one of those macros, the program will break, but the compiler will not generally produce a warning or diagnostic.

Comment: @EricPostpischil : If that is what is happening here, the OP will have to ask about the specific problem rather than this X-Y problem.  The only reasonable answer is "possibly but unlikely (insofar that other explanations are more probable)" is not very helpful in solving the undisclosed problem.

Comment: This isn't always true. There can be conflicts that manifest as a runtime error, like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65068001/7509065