# How to solve the segmentation fault issue when I use Python ctypes to call rs232.c?

Tags: python, c, segmentation-fault, ctypes

I build the rs232.c as a shared library and try to use python3 to call it. But I got the "Segmentation fault" error when try to get the attributes of com port, tcgetattr(). Anyone know what's this problem?
my os system is raspberry pi p3.

testcom.py

```py
from ctypes import *
comdll = cdll.LoadLibrary("rs232.so")
comdll.RS232_OpenComport(c_int(22),c_int(115200),c_char_p(b'8N1'))
```

rs232.c

```c
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define RS232_PORTNR  39
int Cport[RS232_PORTNR],error;
struct termios old_port_settings[RS232_PORTNR];

int RS232_OpenComport(int comport_number, int baudrate, const char *mode)
{
    error = tcgetattr(Cport[comport_number], old_port_settings + comport_number); //segmentation fault at this line
    return error;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you named your variable `error` and made it global. As a GNU extension, [glibc adds a function named `error`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html#index-error), and your library ends up confusing the two and trying to write the return value of `tcgetattr` over the function called `error`. To fix it, either rename `error` to something else, declare it `static`, or move its declaration inside `RS232_OpenComport`.

Comment: Your comment is useful !  Thanks.